# Get an image's position on an html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I'm currently making a game and i do quite a bit of animations to my "player" image.

And then, i was wondering , is there any method, library, ANYTHING that would get the current position of the image relative to my canvas.

the image is created inside the canvas, not a separate tag <img>

Comment: So basically you have drawn an image on the canvas, and now want to find out the position of the image you drew on it? Or is this image a separate `<img>` element?

Comment: Don't you draw your player with a position?

Comment: yes but then as the player moves along its hard to keep up to where he is and might cause problems